# Regular expressions with optional matches with priority to the right

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm not a master of Regular expressions but I get by. I am stumped by this and I wonder if anyone can offer any help. FWIW I am doing this in Ruby. I have a series of hostnames for example

```
demo.some.host
demo-tj.some.host
demo-staging.some.host
demo-tj-staging.some.host
demo-dev-staging.some.host
demo-tj-dev-staging.some.host
```

I want to consistently the tenant and the environment from this.

```
demo, nil
demo-tj, nil
demo, staging
demo-tj, staging
demo, dev-staging
demo-tj, dev-staging
```

I thought this would be relatively easy.

```
> 'demo-dev-staging.test.host'.match(/\A(?<tenant>[a-z\-]+[^\-]{1})?(-(?<env>dev-staging|staging))?\.test\.host\z/)
=> #<MatchData "demo-dev-staging.test.host" tenant:"demo-dev-staging" env:nil>
```

The problem is that the match for the tenant includes characters that are using in the match for environment, even though they are explicit rather than just [a-z]. I had hoped this could perhaps this gave me some kind of priority. However, since they are optional this causes problems. Can this even be solved with a single regex or am I barking up the wrong tree. Can I prioritise a match from the right in favour? I guess I could have multiple regexes that are tested in order but obviously for convenience it's nice to know it matches one regex for one flavour of urls and one for another flavour.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a non-greedy quantifier `*?` on the optional tenant suffixes so the greedy quantifier `?` on the environment can take precedence:

```
/\A(?<tenant>[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*?)(-(?<env>(?:dev-)?staging))?\.test\.host\z/
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ImprobableLeftManagement